# Make Nerdtree Use Choosewin On Open File

Tags: vim, nerdtree

One of my two favorite plugins for *vim* are [NERDTree](https://github.com/scrooloose/nerdtree) and [ChooseWin](https://github.com/t9md/vim-choosewin). Now I rly like to combine them. In fact I want to adjust *NERDTree* this way, that when open a file (`o`) it use *ChooseWin* to ask the user for a window to show the (new) buffer in. The default behaviour is that *NERDTree* always use the last active window (except its own).

I already go trough the documentation of *NERDTree* (cause I guess to create a hook here is a solution), but couldn't find something. The section **API** sounds interest at first, but doesn't help me.

So I just wanna ask the community if someone is hacky enough to find a solution for this.

Comment: At least try something before asking for help.

Comment: @romainl I know, that this is the common pattern. But as I said I read a lot but was not able to find anything. So how should I try something out, if I have't any clue how to start?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution:**

To use the *choosewin* plugin when open a file with *NERDTree*, the function `activateFileNode()` has to be adjusted. The approach is simple: Backup the current window ID, call the *choosewin* function so select a window, jump back to *NERDTree* by the stored ID and then open the file as normal. Cause *NERDTree* always use the last visited window, this solution works.
Saving the window ID and jump back is necessary, cause the following procedure by *NERDTree* to open the file uses variables which are local to their buffer.

**Code**

In *autoload\nerdtree\ui_glue.vim*:

```
function! s:activateFileNode(node)
    let l:nerdwindow = win_getid()
    call choosewin#start(range(1, winnr('$')))
    call win_gotoid(l:nerdwindow) 
    call a:node.activate({'reuse': 'all', 'where': 'p'})
endfunction
```

---

Be aware that this only work, if *choosewin* is installed. So far I don't have a solution how to check this before. Maybe an update follows.

This solution is also available on my [fork](https://github.com/weilbith/nerdtree). As soon as I fixed this "check if plugin exists", I will open a PR.

Answer (score 1):

You'd probably want to fork nerdtree for that

once you've done that you'd change [this function(nerdtree#ui_glue#invokeKeyMap)](https://github.com/scrooloose/nerdtree/blob/master/autoload/nerdtree/ui_glue.vim#L400)

you'd check that `a:key == 'o'`, then you'll need to figure out what's the file under the cursor so that you know what to do after calling ChooseWin. I don't think it's a very simple task, in my experience making sense out of nerdTree's code isn't trivial but if you're willing to make the effort...

Comment: Yes, maybe I've to done this. Guess I'll learn something from that.